# Change Component props using ref

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ref

I want to add a prop to a component using its ref object.
For context, I have a list of objects that are conditionally rendered, I am using the ref to scroll to the component upon click, but I also want it to change props when the click action happens

```js
...
return(
  [
    {
       name: 'Toyota',
       year: '2020'
     },
      {
       name: 'BMW',
       year: '2020'
     },
  ].map(({name, year})=>{

   <someComponent ref={refName}> 

  </someComponent>

})
<a onClick={()=>{refName.ChangeComponentProps}}>Click me!</a>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs) state: **Don’t Overuse Refs**

Refs can be used for setting the scroll, but for things like changing props, you need to define a function to call in that `onClick`, and in that function update some state, then depending on that state, select which prop gets passed into the component.